# Why i cant come back to main input? (python3)

Tags: python

I'm building a terminal project. In my project, when user writes the command, i want to return to main input.

**Codes:**

```
write_Code = input(os.getcwd() + " > ")

# UCD "ls" Code
if write_Code == "ucd --ls":
    print(os.listdir())
```

In this code i created a ls code. When user writes ucd --ls program is ending. But i want to back to main input. I tried while loop but it doesnt work. I research enough but i cant find what can i do

Comment: Share your `while-loop` code by editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop to do this:

```
while True:
    write_Code = input(os.getcwd() + " > ")

    # UCD "ls" Code
    if write_Code == "dir":
        print(os.listdir())
```